# Makefile DEFAULT_GOAL variable

Tags: linux, makefile

This is an example of use of DEFAULT_GOAL Variable:

```
ifeq ($(.DEFAULT_GOAL),)
  $(warning no default goal is set)
endif

.PHONY: foo
foo: ; @echo $@

$(warning default goal is $(.DEFAULT_GOAL))

# Reset the default goal.
.DEFAULT_GOAL :=

.PHONY: bar
bar: ; @echo $@

$(warning default goal is $(.DEFAULT_GOAL))

# Set our own.
.DEFAULT_GOAL := foo


The output is:

no default goal is set
default goal is foo
default goal is bar
foo
```

I stuck up understanding that what is the flow of the **echo and $(warning )** function i.e. when **$(warning )** function is called the **echo $@** output is suppressed and last output of **echo $@** is displayed. Because there is **2 echo statement** and **3 $(warning ) function call** but only one target id printed by echo the last one foo . Why others are not printed and why the last value is printed as foo why not bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings and assignments happen as `make` reads the `Makefile`.  Only then does it begin to decide which of the rules to execute.  The other `echo` statements are never executed because it only makes the default goal at that point, which is `foo`.

Comment: The [How make Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) section of the GNU Make Manual is somewhat helpful here.

Comment: @tripleee ! thanks for early reply I would like to know that which echo $@ statement is executed that has produced the foo as default goal. thanks in advance.

Comment: `$@` is the name of the target, so it's obviously `foo`. The final assignment sets `DEFAULT_GOAL` to `foo` do that's what it's set to when Make has finished reading the file.

Comment: If you are entirely unfamiliar with Make basics, you should perhaps read an introduction and then get back here.

Comment: Thanks for reply!!!! Sir I am doing Makefile first time so want to understand everything clearily so that there is no doubt at all that's why I am assuming nothing. My question may be look like stupid but the reply given by you all make me very clear on every point in makefile. I has been assigned to write makefiles for complex project on Supercomputer but I have not done this before so I am totally newbie to Makefikes. So sir please don't be angry and suggest some links other than GNU Make if possible.  Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out where anger would fit into this picture, but if you have more questions, post them as new questions, where everyone on StackOverflow will see them. I recall the O'Reilly book was a fairly gentle introduction but it's very old already.